# Session and Cookies

Tags: session, cookies

I'm a newbie, so as far as I know, when a client makes a request to the server, the server will create a session, then bind the session id to a cookie and send it back to the user. Each time the user sends a request, including a cookie, the server will check the session ID in the cookies. But what if a cookie is expired? Does the session time out too? Please help me understand this

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to use the cookie sessions for, I usually use the cookie sessions for authenticated users in some of my apps. And if the cookies expires, then this client will have to authenticate his identity by logging in again. Then server will create a new cookie for the client.

Answer (score 0):

When a cookie associated with a session expires, the server may handle it in different ways Like ,It can either invalidate the session, requiring the user to log in again, or renew the session by generating a new session ID.